# Error message "Forbidden You don't have permission to access /~[uname]/***.cgi on this server."

Tags: apache, perl, cgi

I have configured my Apache by myself and have configured CGI on my localhost,
but I received:

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access /[username/**.cgi on this server.

My http.conf(/etc/apache2/httpd.conf)

```
Before: #LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so
After:  LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so

Before: #Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
After:  Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf

Before: #AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
After:  AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .ru .pl
```

My [username].conf(/etc/apache2/users/[username].conf)

```
<Directory "/Users/[username]/Sites/">
  AllowOverride All
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews +ExecCGI
  AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

My cgi file (Users/[username]/Sites/**.cgi)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                                                                                     
print "Content-Type: text/html \n\n"
str = "Hello World"
print str
print "\n"
```

my Apache version:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Unix)
```

And I have tried this command:

```
$ sudo chmod 755 ~/Sites
$ sudo chmod 755 ~/Sites/**.cgi
```

Comment: What are the permissions on `~`?  That needs to be readable and executable by the apache user, too, or else it won't be able to reach `~/Sites`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and the Perl tag. This is a very good first question. :) You have a syntax error in your Perl code. `str = "Hello World"` is wrong. Variables need to have a `$` sigil, so it needs to be `$str = "foo"` and `print $str`. That is not the issue here though.

Answer (score 0):

the first line must be :

> #!/usr/bin/perl -wT

add this two flags (-wT) at the end